# Loading deep learning models on Cloud Run is slower than loading them on Cloud function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-run

I am testing two Google Cloud products, namely: Cloud Functions and Cloud Run. I am leaning toward using cloud run given that it allows you for more customization and observability.

However one thing I noticed that for some reason, Cloud Functions are faster than Cloud Run, despite using the same code and configuration (2 GB RAM). Even increasing RAM or core numbers for Cloud Run didn't improve speed.

My main issue is model loading time (to get a fast cold start), in Cloud Function it takes 1/5 what it takes in Cloud Run, that's very detrimental for my use case.

I ran benchmark tests and this is a re-occurring pattern for many different models, does anyone have an idea on why this is the case ?

**UPDATE**: My dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8
# set a directory for the app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
# copy all the files to the container
COPY . .
# install dependencies
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install Flask gunicorn
RUN apt-get install util-linux
# run the command
CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --timeout 0 main:app
```

Comment: The product are hard to compare. On cloud functions you only provide your code, and Google cloud wrap it in a web server and create a container for you. On Cloud Run, you create your webserver and your container. If you don't use the same optimization/options as Cloud Functions, you won't have the same result, but it's not a question of product, but of container creation. Can you share your dockerfile to see if we can help you to optimise the cold start?

Comment: Thank you for your response, my doubts are that I got something wrong in the gunicorn parameters, maybe using torchserve would be better ? I updated the post with my dockerfile.

Comment: Are you using a custom domain in Cloud Run? Which regions are you comparing?

Comment: When Cloud Run runs for the first time, its instance starts running and requires downloading the container image and starting the container. Additionally, you can refer to this [link](https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-run-minimizing-cold-starts/) that proposes way/s on how to avoid or minimize cold starts in Google Cloud Run.

Comment: @Pentium10 Both of Cloud Function and Cloud Run are us-central1.

Comment: @RJC Thanks for linking the article, however I already read it, it was not helpful. In Cloud Run's documentation they clear state that docker image size doesn't affect loading time. I verified that by checking if the same phenomenon persist for small models (50mb) and big models (1gb). It does indeed persist.

Comment: Hi @user297904, just like what guillaume said, "On Cloud Run, you create your webserver and your container.", each revision is automatically scaled to the number of container instances needed to handle all incoming requests that was stated [here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/about-instance-autoscaling#max-instances). To minimize the impact of cold starts, Cloud Run may keep some instances idle for a maximum of 15 minutes. You can also check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/min-instances) for further details for optimization.

Comment: @RJC Thanks for your reply, I am aware of that guide, however it doesn't answer my question. The difference in performance between cloud function and cloud run is really odd.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Does my dockerfile cause any kind of under performance ?

Comment: I would like to say "yes", because it's what you get, but I can't help you in the optimization. I'm not a python developer, and I don't know the python/gunicorn tweak to speed up your container at runtime.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Okay, thank you for taking the time to look into my question